# Limit and view WPA usage on Windows

Tags: windows, wpa-supplicant, wpa

on my windows operating system, I want to see if my connection uses WPA1 or WPA2.. Or if it uses TKIP or CCMP or GCMP with AES. How can I get the full information of current connection ?

Also, for example if I want the OS to only use TKIP or GCMP as an example, how can I limit that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- Find the Wi-Fi connection icon in the taskbar and click on it
- Then click Properties underneath your current Wi-Fi connection
- Scroll down and look for the Wi-Fi details under Properties
- Under that, look for Security Type, which shows your Wi-Fi protocol

I don't know if there even is a way to force this on the client. I've never tried and this has never come up in my work either. The network encryption type is configured on the infrastructure side. In any case I don't see it as a good idea.

Iif there is a way and you do force a certain way, you will hamper your own connectivity - if you force WPA2/TKIP you won't be able to connect to a network using WPA2/CCMP.